# SQL query to DataTable to include headers

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datatable

Up until now, I had a utility class that contained a function called "getTable", which took a string query and returned a datatable. Now I'm trying to get these queries to be returned via excel. Simply copying the contents of the datatable to excel works fine - however there's no header row on the spreadsheet to explain what each column is.

Below is my attempt:

```
public static DataTable getTable(String sql, bool includeHeaderRow)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        using (SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, getConn()))
        {
            adpt.Fill(table);

            if (includeHeaderRow)
            {
                DataRow headerRow = table.NewRow();

                for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    headerRow[i] = table.Columns[i].ColumnName;
                }

                table.Rows.InsertAt(headerRow, 0);
            }
        }
        return table;
    }
```

The above almost works, but an exception is thrown when I try and write a column name (obviously a string) into a non-string column of the datatable.

Any ideas for an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: You could also WriteXml: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.writexml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. It can be opened in Excel too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course the code may give error, because as you told you are assigning none compatible datatypes into one column with specific datatype, columns at Datatable accepts specific datatypes now if you try to `change the column datatype to object` by creating a copy of table(cloning it) I think the problem will fix:

```
public static DataTable getTable(String sql, bool includeHeaderRow)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        using (SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, getConn()))
        {
            adpt.Fill(table);


            if (includeHeaderRow)
            {    
                DataTable dt = table.Clone();
                for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                  dt.Columns[i].DataType = typeof(Object);
                }
                foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows) 
                {
                   dt.ImportRow(row);
                }
                DataRow headerRow = dt.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    headerRow[i] = table.Columns[i].ColumnName;
                }

                dt.Rows.InsertAt(headerRow, 0);
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
```